# Cannot add event listener to iframe elements even after waiting for .onload

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I am trying for some time now to access the iFrame on my site (mylily.eu/pages/shop-local) and add event listeners to an input field and a button. The problem is that I am using a plugin is embedded in the iFrame so this is why I have to use this workaround in the first place.

I recognized that I have to wait for the DOM in the iFrame to be fully loaded which is why I have added the onload function to the iFrame but somehow it still isn't working and I can't figure out why.

```
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("store-locator-wrapper");

  iframe.onload = function() {

    $('#MapAddress').keypress(function(event){
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if(keycode == '13'){
        document.getElementById("geolocation-failed").style.display="none 
        !important";  
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("lsl-search-button").addEventListener("click", 
    function(){
      document.getElementById("geolocation-failed").style.display="none 
      !important";
    });
  }
</script>
```

What the code is supposed to do is to make the red "Geolocation not found" message disappear which is displayed if a user denies location access from the browser (below the input field).

The message should disappear 
1. If a user presses enter on the input field (first part of the code)
2. If a user clicks the search button below the input field

To see the message you have to go to mylily.eu/pages/shop-local and deny location access.

Comment: You have to tell jQuery that it has to look in the iframe's document, by passing it as the context parameter: `$('#MapAddress', iframe.contenDocument)` **However**, since in your case, the content is from a different origin, you won't be able to access this document, so you are stuck. The only solution for you is to reach out the provider of this plugin, so that they do expose an API to do exactly what you want. For instance, they could listen for the `message` event, and then you could do `frame.postMessage({ action: "killLocationAlert" }, "https://client.lifterlocator.com")`.

Comment: Ah okay. But in the second part where I want to add an event listener to the button I am not using jQuery, just plain JavaScript shouldn't this work somehow? Or is there no chance because the iFrame is hosted somewhere else? @Kaiido

Comment: No chance. You simply can't access this document from your page. No library or anything will change that. Get in touch with this plugin's provider, they may already have a solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!